# What should I do when an answer misses the point of my question (in my opinion), but the community seems to approve the answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

A few times already I have posted questions on Stack Overflow and received answers that the community approves (i.e. the answer gets multiple upvotes), but in my opinion aren't good.

For instance these answers seem to ignore (or misunderstand, maybe) some important points written in the question.

Sometimes, but not always, I find satisfying answers in the discussion in the comments.

How am I supposed to behave in these cases? Should I approve the most upvoted answer, letting the community decide, even if I don't agree with the judgement? Or what else?

And how can I act in the future to minimize these situations?

I can provide links to specific questions, if necessary. (Is it good practice to do that though? I want to avoid anything that might resemble pointing fingers)

Comment: downvote it if you don't find it useful. That's it. Nothing further is needed, you're not obligated to accept it or anything else.

Comment: You do not need to provide the links to the posts as they will suffer the meta effect

Comment: On the other hand, if you review many SO posts, the OP accepts an answer that does not coincide with the most voted one. The fact that the OP accepts an answer implies that it was useful for him but that does not imply that it is correct, and vice versa, that the answer has many UV does not imply that it is correct but that many users like it, in those cases the correct or wrong depends on the focus.

Comment: Granted... you don't actually have the rep to downvote yet, but you're close!

Comment: If you find a comment that answers your question, reply to the comment asking the user to answer or answer, giving credit to the commenter. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/215552)

Comment: Is there any chance that perhaps your Question could easily be misunderstood? But apart from that, don't just accept an Answer just because it's the most upvoted. You don't even have to accept any of the Answers.

Comment: If you believe an author of an answer has misunderstood your question, you have to **edit** your question to clarify it, then as a curiosity ping the author of the answer saying that you believe they might have done so.  If the author of the answer does not improve their answer, and it's not helpful, downvote it.

Comment: @SecurityHound I'd caution against that. It's a very poor practice to change a question in such a way to invalidate existing answers. So, if the answer fit the initial question, then it's probably best to leave it and re-ask making sure to be clearer.

Comment: @VLAZ - I am not talking about a completely different question, I am talking about clarifying the question, if the a misunderstanding exists.  Honestly, asking the same question again (even if you clarify it) will probably not result in that. We question being answered.

Comment: @SecurityHound doesn't need to be completely different to invalidate an answer. Q: "I want to do X" -> A: "Then do Y and Z" -> edit to the Q: "I want to do X without doing Y". It's still the same question but the existing answer is now rendered invalid. That's why clarifications that *make* an answer wrong should be avoided. If the answer *was* wrong and an edit merely tries to draw attention to the correct requirement would be fine. It's sometimes hard to thread the line between what is or isn't changing the question substantially enough.