# Why can't we undelete comments?

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

I believe it would be a nice feature to have, to be able to undelete comments, sometimes a recently deleted comment gets feedback after, leaving it out of context, of course one can always leave a new one but the timeline makes it difficult to make sense of it and is less practical.

Here is a simple example:

[image]

The above example is kind of harmless, and the commenter was nice enough to provide some context, that doesn't always happen, there are circumstances where deleted comments may be important to understand the OP, or for the OP to understand the comments.

Is there any problems or drawbacks about this feature, or some reasoning on why this can't be done?

Comment: You are basically describing a comment which should have been an answer.

Comment: Relevant: [What comments are actually for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If they contain useful info they should either lead to an edit to the question or the posting of an answer.

Comment: @Gimby,fair point, but maybe not, many users don't answer whe they feel the problem doesn't deserve a full answer, I know this is not ideal but it's impossible to force people to always follow the strict website guidelines. Besides many comments are used for clarification, not naswering, and group of comments may provide a solution to the OP without the need of an answer.

Comment: @JeanneDark I appreciate the link, and it makes sense, but not all is black and white, sometimes a relevant comment may not fall in either of those two categories.

Comment: People could just... Not delete their comments if they think they're of any value? If they delete it and it wasn't of any value and they get a response, then the response equally will have no value and can be flagged for deletion. And if it [the response] _does_ have value on its own... Well then there's no need to undelete the source.

Comment: Relevant: [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597/11682469)

Comment: @Nick I understand this is a *corner case* but there question here is feedback after the comment was deleted that makes the seemingly unimportant comment become relevant again, this is not a *must have* feature, but it would be nice to have, and it doesn't seem all that hard to implement.

Comment: Well.... If you can find a legitimate case of this happening where the responding comment can't simply be edited to remove any reliance on a source comment and where the comments shouldn't simply be written as an answer or an edit, I may give you an upvote

Comment: @Nick, point taken, as I said this may not happen every day, you have surely come across comment sections that make no sense at all and it's clear that it's because of missing comments, I know I have. I'm just saying it would be nice to have this feature. That said for an upvote I'll try to find a meaningful example :-)

Comment: I have, but that's generally because all the comments should be deleted and only 1 person cleaned up after themselves ;)

Comment: This feature could be abused, eg. post an unfriendly comment reply and quickly delete it to hide it temporarily. Later undelete it (eg. after comment purge, when the discussion has moved on and addressee can not well respond, or when addressee may have left).

Comment: @JeanneDark, fair point, I hadn't look at it that way. You may consider making your comment an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a user self-deletes a comment and wants it published again, they can just re-post it.

Deleting and undeleting a comment would particularly interact badly with comment flags, making taking care of comments that need deletion harder

Also, mess with the comment thread flow

All without gaining anything in exchange.

Comment: Fun fact: Mods can not undelete comments which are deleted by their authors... Mods can only undelete comments deleted by mods.

Comment: @Cerbrus That is incorrect. Moderators *can* undelete comments made or deleted by anyone. Doing so is not provided as a part of the stock UI, but it's easy to just add an "Undelete" button, which is all that's needed. There's at least one userscript which automatically adds them to all deleted comments.

Comment: Oh, that's what I've been told by a moderator, once... He was very insistent that a user deleting their own comments is final. Maybe that userscript isn't "working as intended", when it enables you to do that?

Comment: @Cerbrus the moderator is just informing you what the UI presents to you. That it isn't enforced by the back end is another issue. But only ~150 users have that issue anyways.