# Can anyone else other than the question poster mark an answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers

Does anyone else other the original poster have the ability to mark an answer to a question as the answer or solution to the question? Many posters who are new to the site either do not know to mark an answer or just leave a thank you comment.

Would it be a better for someone such as a gold badge expert in certain domain be able to "mark as answer" if the person who posted the question did not select an answer and just left a thank you comment?

Comment: Nope, only the asker has that privilige. related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313206/encourage-users-to-accept-answers

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277918/should-users-with-high-rep-be-able-to-accept-answers-to-questions-with-no-accept

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, only the OP has "mark as answer" privileges. Theoretically they're the best placed to say "this answer helped me the most".

Votes are meant to denote that "objectively this is the best answer", or probably more accurately, "this answer helped the most people".